# QLPreviewController Overlay

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, label, qlpreviewcontroller

I'm creating a `QLPreviewController`:

```
func numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController(controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
return 1
}

func previewController(controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAtIndex index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {

let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "pdf")
let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)

return url
}

@IBAction func previewAction(sender: AnyObject) {
let preview = QLPreviewController()
preview.dataSource = self
self.presentViewController(preview, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now I want to add onto the `QLPreviewController` some kind of Overlay, at last a Label (that should always be seen).
Is there a way todo so?

Comment: Did you already tryed to subclass QLPreviewController and just add a label with addSubview?f

Comment: yes i did and this did not work for me

Comment: any solution? why did the subclass not work?